# Swift REALM - sort by distance, filter and store only unique value

Tags: swift, realm

Hi I am making an app that show me interesting places. Its showing places in radius. I am using REALM to store values.
However realm don't know how to make Unique values. I am using this for Unique rows.

```
let result:[String] = realm.objects(E21).sorted("name").uniqueValue("Id_prov", type: String.self)
```

This for finding things in region around me

```
var datasourceE21Distance:Results<E21> = realm.findInRegion(E21.self, region: curentRegion).filter(tempRequest)
```

But i don't know how to combine these things to one and then sort it from closes one to me to the most far.

I will be glad for any help here.

EDIT i am using these two extensions found:

```
func findInRegion<T: Object>(type: T.Type, region: MKCoordinateRegion, latitudeKey: String = "lat", longitudeKey: String = "lng") -> Results<T> {
    // Query
    return self
        .objects(type)
        .filterGeoBox(region.geoBox, latitudeKey: latitudeKey, longitudeKey: longitudeKey)

}

func uniqueValue<U : Equatable>(paramKey: String, type: U.Type)->[U]{
    var uniqueValues : [U] = [U]()
    for obj in self {

        if let val = obj.valueForKeyPath(paramKey) {

            if (!uniqueValues.contains(val as! U)) {
                uniqueValues.append(val as! U)
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueValues
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[RealmGeoQueries](https://github.com/mhergon/RealmGeoQueries), the library you're using for filtering your entities by a bounding box, supports sorting objects by distance via `sortByDistance`. This returns an array as this operation has to be done in memory with cached distances.

You would need to make sure that you're `uniqueValue` method is defined in an extension on `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something like this. But it can't filter right away :-/

```
let currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat!, longitude: currentLng!)
            sortedObjectsByDistance = realm.findNearby(E21.self, origin: currentLocation, radius: 50000.0, sortAscending: true, latitudeKey: "lat", longitudeKey: "lng")
            var seenIdProv:[String:Bool] = [:]
            sortedObjectsByDistance = sortedObjectsByDistance.filter {
                seenIdProv.updateValue(false, forKey: $0.Id_prov) ?? true
            }
```